# Spring Batch job execution status in response body

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm very new to Spring Batch and pretty confused

I've got a controller with some request mappings. When I get a certain URL I want to print the job status to the response body. Here's some code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batchExecution", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getJobExecutionStatus() {
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

I've tried adding JobExecution to the method, but can you only access these elements with the JobExecutionListener?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batchExecution", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getJobExecutionStatus(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

sorry for my noobie questions, I can't find any documentation on what I'm looking for

Comment: look for JobExplorer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html
You can autowire it and get everything you want.

Comment: @PospolitaNikita I'm confused though, to use getJobInstance from JobExplorer you need to provide an instanceId...how can you obtain this?

Comment: You can call ".findJobInstancesByJobName", then get any JobInstance to provide to ".getJobExecutions"

Comment: @PospolitaNikita Once again, you have to provide a jobName, start, and count? I don't understand calling those methods without knowing that information

Comment: You already have JobName, if you use Spring Batch. Just look to implementation of this method to get meanings of "start" and "count". I think you can just use 0 and 100 for testing.
Another path to check docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#batchArchitectureConsiderations
All jobExecutions can be stored in DB, so you can just get this info out of there.

Comment: @PospolitaNikita Thank you, I'll do some research based off what you've said. I'll see where it takes me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I was able to answer my own question with the help of Pospolita Nikita's comments on my original post.

I implemented a service with a process method, and then called that method in my program controller. The code looks like this:

**Service**

```
@Override
    public String process(Long jobId) throws Exception {
        BatchStatus jobStatus = explorer.getJobExecution(jobId).getStatus();
        LOGGER.info("The Job ID is: " + jobId);
        LOGGER.info("The job status is: "+jobStatus);
        return null;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batchMonitor/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> process(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = MccControllerUtils.createCacheDisabledHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Obtaining job by ID " + id);
            String response = batchService.process(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error obtaining batch by ID " + id, e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this can help someone else down the road. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you add a service which is called by your controller and run the batch job inside and get back to execution status to return it